# how to move a photo from a folder on sd card to another folder?

Tags: android

My problem is to cut out an image from a folder and paste that image in another folder.
I've searched but have not been able to implement this problem!

for example:

**File file1 = new File("mnt/sdcard/kaic1/imagem.jpg");**

for

**File file2 = new File("mnt/sdcard/Kaic2/");**

Comment: Whatever you do, you should use Environment.getExternalStorage() to get the sdcard root directory rather than assuming it's at /mnt/sdcard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A better solution to this problem would be:

```
File from = new File(Environment.getExternalStorage().getAbsolutePath()+"/kaic1/imagem.jpg");
File to = new File(Environment.getExternalStorage().getAbsolutePath()+"/kaic2/imagem.jpg");
from.renameTo(to);
```

You can't assume that the sdcard is at `/mnt/sdcard`. Newer devices, such as a Nexus four, don't even have sdcards. Their storage is at `/storage/emulated/0`. It's always better to ask the OS where something is than to make assumptions (as ethan pointed out.)

Comment: ok, but this code is only done the name change, or am I mistaken?
I wanted something like ctrl + x to a file in a folder and then ctrl + v in another folder!

Comment: By changing the name, you are essentially moving it. If you change the name of `/a/b/c.d` to `/a/e/c.d` you have moved `c.d` to `e` from `b`. The filesystem entry to `c.d` has changed.

Comment: Conversely, to rename a file in linux, you can use the move command, `mv`. Renaming is just an abstraction of moving.

Comment: If I answered your question, press the green check mark underneath the voting control so this answer appears closed. If I haven't I would love to provide clarification so I can answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
File file1 = new File("mnt/sdcard/kaic1/imagem.jpg");
File file2 = new File("mnt/sdcard/Kaic2/imagem.jpg");

file1.renameTo(file2);
```

Here's more info on the `renameTo` function:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#renameTo(java.io.File)

**Edit:** also check Osmium USA's answer regarding hard-coding the "mnt/sdcard/" folder path in your code.

Comment: ok, but this code is only done the name change, or am I mistaken?
I wanted something like ctrl + x to a file in a folder and then ctrl + v in another folder!

Comment: You have to introduce a variable in your application (let's say mCopyFile) which you set to "mnt/sdcard/kaic1/imagem.jpg" when the user of your application executes "Cut" command. Then call the "renameTo" function when the user executes "Paste" command, passing the mCopyFile variable which your remembered in the previous step.